# Audio Podcast Feed Reader Service

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, rss-reader

I am new to podcasting, so this might be newbie question. 
I have a Podcast which I have hosted on pinecast.com. I have the RSS feed of the podcast which I want to incorporate in my Website.

Is there any RSS Feed Reader in Angular/Bootstrap which will take each of the episodes and render with the episode title, bio and the audio to play it.

My website is built on angular2/bootstrap.

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you try to implement it yourself?

Comment: Yes, I am attempting that, but I was wondering if someone has done is already. As I said, I am new to podcast streaming and hence I didn't want to put this on my website and have it fail..

Answer (score 0):

I used FeedMe npm module along with angular2 to write my own component. I used the tutorial from https://github.com/becompany/angular2-rss-reader-tutorial which is a very good starting point

Comment: Actually, I have forked the original repo and the fork is available at https://github.com/Chan4077/angular-rss-reader and the website at https://angular-rss-reader.firebaseapp.com.